# Karate Netty capabilities

Tags: karate

we've been doing some proof of concept work around Karate-netty's mocking capabilities, and we're wondering about potential future capabilities for the following:

- Dynamically add / remove mock features to the server after it's started up (e.g. more tightly couple the mocks to the individual test cases)
- Leverage multiple mock features (or nested) at start-up

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: just edited and added a point

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion things are fine the way it is.

- Mocks are so lightweight that creating one for each unit test is practical. you can re-use seed data if needed
- Best practice is use one mock for multiple end-points. but nothing stops you from starting more than one, you just have to keep track of the instances
- Actually you can add an endpoint to a mock yourself that only serves as a way for external tests to modify the state of the mock ! Karate turns traditional mocking on it's head - basically saying you can write real services that work, with minimal effort

It may be more meaningful to discuss real code examples if you have some.